# SAS drive to SAS/SATA backplane then SATA cables to SAS/SATA RAID card?

Tags: hardware, hard-drive, connection, sata, sas

I just got a Supermicro chasis: 
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816101241

That has a backplane that supports SAS and SATA drives but the backplane has SATA ports to be connected to the motherboard. I have a LSI Megaraid card (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816118129) that supports both SAS and SATA.

My question is can I take my SAS drive and hook it to the backplane, then use SATA breakout cables to connect to the LSI Megaraid card since the card is as SAS controller?

I wasn't sure if there were limitations on the cables themselves between SAS and SATA.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an update.

I went ahead and I risked one Cheetah drive to this experiment and it seemed to have worked fine.

So then I hooked up the rest of the 3 drives (4 total) and initialized a RAID 5 array on them.

So far so good. I'll install an OS and run some IO testing and report back if people are curious.

Answer (score 0):

Doing same thing here - that should work fine.  I've read some stuff about mixing SATA and SAS drives on the backplane you might want to watch for.

Comment: Do you want to elaborate on what you read that might cause the op issues?